# Uncheck Radio Button jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Sometimes we need to uncheck a radio button using jQuery, but all answers turns complicated. Well, I'll gonna show you an easy way to do it.

In the below code, we can see that all we need is the name of the radio and use the attribute checked.

```
$('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').attr("checked" , false );
```

Comment: Use `prop('checked', false)`

Comment: Is there a question here or is this just an outdated public service announcement?

Comment: @j08691 Maybe edit [this image](http://cdn.theatlantic.com/assets/media/img/mt/2014/09/The_More_You_Know/lead_large.png) into the post?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method like following

```js
$('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').prop("checked" , false );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" checked />
```

Comment: Thanks man, prop is an another alternative.